# WORDPRESS - Font-Awesome Icons not showing in firefox, showing in chrome & IE

Tags: firefox, wordpress, font-awesome

Ive tried to implement font-awesome icons into my main menu, and use a plugin that also utilizes font-awesome icons.

My issue is that the icons work fine in Chrome and IE, but they do not show in Firefox at all.

I have looked for a solution, the common fix did not work for me:

```
<FilesMatch ".(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Here is how the icon looks in firefox:
http://gyazo.com/c912fd997ccd70cb6b499696d8d49dda

I am currently using the Font-Awesome 4 Menus Plugin
http://wordpress.org/plugins/font-awesome-4-menus/

The code I am inserting to get the icon to show is:

```
<i class="fa fa-download fa-1x" style="color: #ff6600;"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

if u added wp_head() in your header please remove it and try again. this helps me . after removing that i got the icons working in firefox also. please note remove only wp_head() do not remove wp_footer() from footer.php.